# Access selected dynamic control in another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two aspx pages, "source.aspx" and "destination.aspx". I have placed a placeholder control in source.aspx, then populated it with linkbuttons programmatically as (this is the source.aspx.cs file):

```
LinkButton[] link = new LinkButton[n]; //where n is the no. of records in my databse
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select column from table", con);
OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //reading column from the database
int i = 0;
while (rd.Read())
        {
            link[i] = new LinkButton();
            link[i].ID = "link" + i;
            link[i].Text = rd[0].ToString();//value read from the database becomes the text for linkbutton
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(link[i]);//adding the link to the placeholder
            i++;
}
```

the source for this page (source.aspx) is:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <p>
        <br />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Now, in destination.aspx, I want to access the text of the linkbutton that was clicked on source.aspx. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to explain why you're doing this, as there might be a better way. In general, a link button should submit back to its own page, unless you have changed the postback location for the form. This is where more information would be useful; do you really need to postback to a different page?

Also, dynamically generated controls are a bit trickier to work with. Unless you call the code to regenerate the controls every time the page loads (i.e. on initial load and postbacks) then the control properties won't be available.

If you were submitting back to the same page, AND regenerating all of the link buttons, then in the click event handler, the text property is available as

```
((LinkButton)sender).Text
```

You cast the sender object as a link button, and then access its Text property.

Edit based on your comment below:

Ok so the easiest way to achieve that is to use a hyperlink rather than a linkbutton, and pass the hyperlink text in the querystring.

You also don't appear to get any benefit from having the links in an array, so you could ditch that variable, and just do this in the loop:

```
while (rd.Read())
        {
            HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
            link.ID = "link" + i;
            link.Text = rd[0].ToString();//value read from the database becomes the text for linkbutton
            link.NavigateUrl = "Destination.aspx?linktext=" + rd[0].ToString();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(link);//adding the link to the placeholder
            i++;
}
```

In the destination.aspx page, the value is available as Request.QueryString("linktext"). Note also that you can call the query string variable anything you like (replace "linktext" with whatever you want). And also, it'd be better if you worked off something short like an id rather than the text of the link, if you can.

Comment: Basically, in source.aspx the program reads column1 from my database and then dynamically populates the placeholder with linkbuttons, where the text of each linkbutton is the column entry read. Thus, the no. of linkbuttons equals the no. of records in my database. Now, each of these linkbuttons, on being clicked, should redirect the user to destination.aspx, whose content depends on the linkbutton clicked. The same page (destination.aspx) will load different content based on the linkbutton clicked. That is why I have provided an ID to all link buttons. So, how do I do this?

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can you please elaborate on how to use querystring?

Comment: Edited my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

**using:**
*read value in other page that it's url contain ?linktext="..."*
    Request.QueryString["linktext"]